# ImportError: No module named _shim

Tags: python, module, pyinstaller, python-2.x, fiona

I am using PyInstaller to generate an executable from a python script. This is what I did:

```
sudo python2 -m PyInstaller ptemplatized.spec
```

It builds successfully the **.exe** but when I execute it I get the following error:

```
[19878] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_mpldata.py
[19878] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py
[19878] LOADER: Running pyi_rth__tkinter.py
[19878] LOADER: Running pyi_rth_pkgres.py
[19878] LOADER: Running physiocap_templatized.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abderrahmen/Bureau/PC/pour/physiocap_templatized.py", line 38, in <module>
    import geopandas
  File "/tmp/pip-build-2qvLhV/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geopandas/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from geopandas.io.file import read_file
  File "/tmp/pip-build-2qvLhV/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/geopandas/io/file.py", line 4, in <module>
    import fiona
  File "/tmp/pip-build-2qvLhV/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fiona/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from fiona.collection import BytesCollection, Collection
  File "/tmp/pip-build-2qvLhV/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 395, in load_module
  File "/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fiona/collection.py", line 9, in <module>
    from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
  File "/tmp/pip-build-2qvLhV/pyinstaller/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 684, in load_module
  File "fiona/ogrext.pyx", line 1, in init fiona.ogrext
ImportError: No module named _shim
[19878] Failed to execute script ptemplatized
```

I tried looking for the module but it seems to not exist. Thank you.

---

**EDIT:**

So I got this answer on another website:

> Fiona has extension modules and some fairly complicated logic in its
>   setup script to manage them with respect to different versions of the
>   GDAL library. This is why python setup.py build (as reported in
>   another issue) won't work, you have to do python setup.py build_ext
>   build. I think you'll need to find a way for pyinstaller to run the
>   build_ext command defined in fiona's setup.py and then you'll be all
>   set.

Can anyone tell me how can that be done in my case?

---

**EDIT2:**

I countred this error by installing an ancient gdal version using a tuto. Now my `Pyinstaller` creates the `.exe` without errors bur when I execute it on another Machine I get the same error. Isn't the goal from using `PyInstaller` is to execute an `.exe` file without having to install all modules? Why am I having an import error if `PyInstaller` worked well and created a proper `.exe`? Thanks